# Variable explorer extension causing conflict with dill package

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed the variable explorer extension in Jupyter notebook using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

and after enabling it,
I was trying to dump my session using `dill` package, but it gave me error.

When I uninstalled my extension then dill worked.
Do it mainly occurs due to package conflicts?
Is there a way by which we can use both the functionalities: Variable extension as well as dill package?

Comment: It could help if your provide the error message and versions of the packages.

Comment: The error which i am getting is : 
TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__


.It is working fine, when i am disabling the variable inspector extension.
The version of dill package which i am using is 0.2.8.2